# Finite sum of Fibonacci numbers in an arithmetic sequence

Tags: summation, fibonacci-numbers

Is there a closed form expression for $G(n,k,m)=\sum_{i=0}^{n}F_{ik+m}$ or at least for $G(n,k,1)$?

I could find
\begin{align}
G(n,k,0)&=\frac{F_{nk+k}-(-1)^kF_{nk}-F_k}{L_k-(-1)^k-1}\\\\
&=G(n,k,1)-G(n,k,-1)
\end{align}
(with $L$ as the Lucas number), but no expression for $m\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Hint:  use the [Binet Formula](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Binet%27s_Formula).

Comment: @lulu: Thanks for the hint. The Binet formula can be used to prove a closed expression. I'm looking for an expression without having to use real numbers.

Comment: Why?   In any case, Binet will hand you the formula, which can then be proved by induction.

Comment: @lulu: ok, [I see](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/323058/817489).